# How is this code achieving transmission of data to a socket correctly?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, sockets

I am currently learning to search for vulnerabilities in C source code. The snippet below is part of a big snippet of code to find vulnerabilities in. Whilst I would not like spoilers, I was wondering if someone could clarify what the code is actually doing in the first place since I can't wrap my head around it!

The function is:

```c
int writeSock(int sock, char *buf, size_t len)
{
    ssize_t byteswrote = 0;
    ssize_t ret = 0;

    while (byteswrote < len)
    {
        ret = send(sock, buf + byteswrote, len - byteswrote, 0);

        if (ret < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (ret == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        byteswrote += ret;
    }

    return byteswrote;
}
```

If on the first iteration of the while loop, it is copying from the start of the buffer to start of buffer + (len - byteswrote) (how much we want to copy - 0) then haven't we copied everything at that point? Why would we need to iterate here as it surely handles everything in one iteration?

Perhaps I'm looking at this in a very stupid way, but I'm struggling with it for some reason.

Comment: Could it be that `send` returns the number of bytes actually transmitted? That is: you ask it to transmit 2000 bytes but at the first call it only transmit 1400 so that you need to call again to send the remaining 600 bytes. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html

Comment: @4386427 Which part of the man page describes the functionality you're talking about?

Comment: This: "RETURN VALUE        
       On success, these calls return the number of bytes sent.  On error,
       -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If on the first iteration of the while loop, it is copying from the
>   start of the buffer to start of buffer + (len - byteswrote) (how much
>   we want to copy - 0) then haven't we copied everything at that point?

Not necessarily.

> Why would we need to iterate here as it surely handles everything in
>   one iteration?

Because it *doesn't* necessarily handle everything in one call, though I can understand how that might not be clear from the `send()` documentation in, say, [its Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html) or [its POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html).

It is more clear in the Linux manual but also documented by POSIX that `send()`'s behavior is specified in terms of variations on the behavior of `write()`, as directed by the flags, if any, passed to `send()`.  The documentation for `write()` is explicit that short writes can occur:

> `write()` writes up to count bytes from the buffer starting at `buf`
>   to the file referred to by the file descriptor `fd`.
>
> The number of bytes written may be less than `count` if, for example,
>   there is insufficient space on the underlying physical medium, or the
>   `RLIMIT_FSIZE` resource limit is encountered (see
>   `setrlimit`**`(2)`**), or the call was interrupted by a signal handler
>   after having written less than `count` bytes.

([Linux manual page for `write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html))

POSIX has substantially the same provisions, but it's documentation does not, IMO, put them in such clear terms.

To support this behavior, `send()` and `write()` return the number of bytes actually sent.  And note, too, that there is no guarantee at this point that the bytes sent have been *received* -- the sent bytes may not have even made it out of the machine yet when the function returns (i.e. they may be buffered).

It is thus absolutely correct and non-redundant to put `send()` and `write()` calls in loops such as you present in your question when one wants to ensure that the full number of bytes specified are in fact sent.  It is in fact a sadly common flaw to fail to do so.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is obvious - `send()` does not guarantee that all of the data will be sent, thus it's returning how much was actually sent to the socket, similar to `write()` function on file operations.

Two cents from my side: in your code if `send()` returned zero will break the loop. However, this is not considered as an error. This might happen, for example, if buffer is full. But I cannot recall I ever experienced this.

Excerpt from `man send`:

> RETURN VALUE
>   On success, these calls return the number of bytes sent.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

Comment: I know you said it's obvious, but as a beginner reading a man page that is supposed to explicit define everything I didn't consider this after I hadn't found anything about how much it sends. Thanks for your answer Andrejs.

Should I assume that network and file operation methods will always behave like that?

Comment: Alhough in most cases all the data will be consumed in one go, you absolutely need to assume it will behave like that, yes.

Comment: I also thought that if the protocol being used TCP, that the re-transmission of data that failed to reach its destination was handled at the protocol level, not in some high level C code :/

Comment: That is correct, @FelipeWarrener-Iglesias, retransmissions are handled by the network stack, not by user code.  Retransmissions have nothing to do with the caller-facing behavior of `send()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger but isn't the loop here trying to re-send the bytes that didn't make it to the destination? Or we assuming the issue with it not being sent is not at the network level or it would theoretically sort itself (tcp retransmitting)?

Comment: John is right. However, I *have* to mention that in case of UDP packets are not guaranteed to be received even after succesfull send. This is a separate topic, of course.

Comment: @FelipeWarrener-Iglesias It has nothing to do with retransmissions. Consider this as splitting into chunks.

Comment: No, @FelipeWarrener-Iglesias, looping serves to dispatch bytes that were never sent in the first place.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs  And at the risk of adding confusion, it's possible that messages over a certain size can't be sent at all.  Per[ the POSIX `send()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html):  "If the message is too long to pass through the underlying protocol, `send()` shall fail and no data shall be transmitted."

Comment: @AndrewHenle that only applies to message-oriented transports like UDP, not to stream-oriented transports like TCP. For TCP, `send()` will either 1) block the caller until some bytes can be sent, if the socket is blocking, 2) fail with `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN` if the socket is non-blocking and no buffer space is available, or 3) fail if the connection has been closed/lost, or some other error has occurred.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The original question doesn't specify whether it's TCP or UDP - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

`send()` is a POSIX function.  Per [the POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `send()` function shall initiate transmission of a message from
>   the specified socket to its peer. ...
>
> ...
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion, `send()` shall return the number of bytes
>   sent. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the
>   error.
>
> ...
>
> **APPLICATION USAGE**
>
> If the socket argument refers to a connection-mode socket, the
>   `send()` function is equivalent to `sendto()` (with any value for the
>   `dest_addr` and `dest_len` arguments, as they are ignored in this
>   case). If the socket argument refers to a socket and the flags
>   argument is 0, the `send()` function is equivalent to [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html).

Note how it's stated that if the `flags` argument is zero, `send()` acts as `write()` would.  That is exactly how the code you posted is using `send()`.  So it works just like `write()` and the `write()` documentation is relevant, too. The [POSIX documentation for `write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) states:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `write()` function **shall attempt to write** `nbyte` bytes ...
>
> ...
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return **the number of
>   bytes actually written** ...

If your operating system's man page fails to note that `send()` can potentially partially send the data requested, your operating system's documentation is deficient.